# Is there a UX site with active threaded forum discussions?

Tags: resources

I'm looking for UX discussion forums and haven't found many active ones.  Maybe I'm googling wrong?

This site has a chat/discussion area which is nice, but is not really the traditional threaded topic style discussion forum.

So does such an active UX forum site exist?

Comment: I think this belongs on meta.

Comment: How is it meta it's not about this site.  I only mention this site as not having what I was looking for.  Man people on the stack sites seem to love moving questions around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not to my knowledge, but perhaps a much better UX question is, "WHY are there no/few traditional UX discussion forums?"

In the evolving web, traditional, threaded discussion forums are becoming a thing of the past. Why? Traditional forums are usually built around legacy principles. They tend to lack or aren't built around these features/ideas which today's web demands:

- Article tagging instead of categorization/filing
- User contribution, feedback, and interactivity
- Some form of social networking/profiling (they can become "cliquey")
- Scalability and user or 'intelligent' customization
- Performance

I always used to add forums to the sites I built... but that was years ago. I see this less and less now.

Anyway, on Stack Exchange sites I find what I am interested in, good at, etc, much quicker than I do on any traditional forum. So I know I haven't directed you to a good, active, UX forum, but at least now you can know why.

Comment: Good points, but I think the asker is looking more for a site where he can discuss UX rather than participate in Q&A, I'm not entirely sure if they really require a forum or if that's just how they're used to looking for "discussion" areas.

Comment: Valid. I wish I could have been more help there. :) Perhaps some specific types of UX discussion would be available, e.g. website design, iPhones/Androids, or other particular platforms. There are plenty of all of those types of forums.

Comment: There's plenty of web design forums, the only discussion/forum based ux things I'm familiar with are some linkedin groups. While I love the idea of linkedin I hesitate to actually recommend them...the site is rather awkward and they're not very large communities.